# How to design this type of sentence in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got overflow error in my ipad app which is design in flutter but can't get the exact ui.
[image]

below is the code snippet which i tried.

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Rebars were ASTM grade  ',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: labelSize),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 30,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: '20',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '  and were placed in general accordance with ACI code 318.',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: labelSize),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: use `Text.rich()` widget

Comment: @pskink i tried but still got the error.

Comment: i mean use just one `Text.rich` instead of `Row`

Comment: @pskink I got your point, many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Text.rich()` constructor i got the solution.

```
return Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: <InlineSpan>[
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                height: 30,
                child: Text('Rebars were ASTM grade  ')),
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 30,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: '20',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Container(
              height: 30,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
              child: Text(
                  '   and were placed in general accordance with ACI code 318.'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: btw use [TextSpan, WidgetSpan, TextSpan] unless you really need that `height: 30`

Comment: `Text.rich` has `style` parameter as I remember - it applies to all TextSpans imho

Comment: i didn't find ```style``` parameter in ```Text.rich``` can you tell me how to align this all three widget in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :

```
 Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Rebars were ASTM grade',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 35,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: '20',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                '  and were placed in general accordance with ACI code 318.',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below makes use of `Expanded`, `Text.rich`, `TextSpan`, and `WidgetSpan` widgets. Read more from the [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html)

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: "Rebars were ASTM grade  ",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 30,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: '20',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: "  and were placed in general accordance with ACI code 318.",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```